# Interacting with randomly created circles in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to make a code where random circles will pop up on the screen and the user has to click them to make them disappear. I am currently having problems with interacting with my circles.

I have made a code to interact with the canvas, but can't seem to figure out how to do the same with the circles. I'm not sure where to put the "clickCircle" function and how to call for it later on.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
      <style type="text/css">
       
      #canvas{
              display:inline;
              margins:auto;
              background-color:lightblue;}

      </style>
    <canvas id="canvas" height="500" width="700" ></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');    
        
      function randomize(){

        var radius = Math.floor(Math.random()*30)+5;
        var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*600)+50;
        var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*400)+50;
        drawCircle(x,y,radius);
        var index = 0;


     function drawCircle(x,y,radius){
       
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x,y,radius,0,2*Math.PI);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
        ctx.fill();

     function clickCircle(){
        console.log('Clicked circle');} 
}
}

  var intervall = setInterval(randomize,1000);


      canvas.addEventListener('click', () => {
            '?'.clickCircle();
            console.log('Clicked canvas');
      });


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you asking "how do I tell which of my randomly generated circles has been clicked?"

Answer (score 0):

You need to close each function individually, and not nest them as you have done.

Also, you don't need `'?'.` to call the `clickCanvas()` function, it can just be deleted.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
          <style type="text/css">
           
          #canvas{
                  display:inline;
                  margins:auto;
                  background-color:lightblue;}
    
          </style>
        <canvas id="canvas" height="500" width="700" ></canvas>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
          var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');    
            
          function randomize(){
    
            var radius = Math.floor(Math.random()*30)+5;
            var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*600)+50;
            var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*400)+50;
            drawCircle(x,y,radius);
            var index = 0;}
    
    
         function drawCircle(x,y,radius){
           
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x,y,radius,0,2*Math.PI);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
            ctx.fill();}
    
         function clickCircle(){
            console.log('Clicked circle');} 
    
    
   
      var intervall = setInterval(randomize,1000);
    
    
          canvas.addEventListener('click', () => {
                clickCircle();
                console.log('Clicked canvas');
          });
    
    
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```